# While reading a xml file in python some inline tags like <sup> don't read complete text?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

The `<sup></sup>` tag interrupts text reading in Python. It stops `Categorical variables were compared using the χ<sup>2</sup>test.` at X and don't print further text.

```
<Abstract>
         <AbstractText> The disease free survival (DFS) and overall survival (OS) were calculated by the Kaplan-Meier method. Categorical variables were compared using the χ<sup>2</sup>test.</AbstractText>
</Abstract>
```

Comment: My understanding of this question got interrupted by not enough context to groke it. Please explain better.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible solutions:

1) What parser are you using to read this xml file? I know ElementTree's itertext() method parses out all text from all subElements of the chosen Element.

2) It might not be the reader at all, but the weird 'X' symbol right before the first sup tag. How is your text encoded? Can it read such a symbol?